# Cut rectangle from the image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, node-imagemagick

I have a png image.
How can I cut a small rect from this image using imagemagick? (make a transparent hole in image)

For example:

Source:

[image: Source]

Destination:

[image: Destination]

Answer (score 3):

It seems I figure it out.

```
convert u1.png -alpha set -region 40x30+15+5 -alpha transparent u3.png
```

It cuts a rect (40x30) from u1.png

Comment: I believe the `-alpha set` is unnecessary.

Comment: Without -alpha set, the second image is completely transparent

Comment: @Rodion unfortunately, I don't get this to work with ImageMagick7.1 Error: "wrong" parameter `-alpha`. But here is a (longer) solution (in the comments) which seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823099/7295599