# Imagemagick remove Area of a Image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to remove a area from a image but I am not sure where to look at.
Let me give you a example.

Source:
[image]

Destination:

[image]

So, I've removed 100x100 a area starting at 100x100 pixels.
Could someone please guide me where to look at?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to paint a white rectangle on an image. So if you want a white rectangle 100px wide and 20px tall, offset 10px from the left side and 20px from the top, use:

```
magick input.png -fill white -draw "rectangle 10,20 110,40" result.png
```

So, if I use a 200x100 magenta input image, I get:

[image]

---

Following on from the comments, here is an example if you have an image with no existing transparency:

[image]

And to *"punch a transparent hole"* we create a new layer the same size as the image, filled with white then draw a black hole in it, and push the result into the transparency layer of the original:

```
magick image.png \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100% -fill black -draw "rectangle 20,10 300,40" \) -alpha off -compose copy-alpha -composite result.png
```

[image]

If the original image already has transparency which we don't want to replace entirely, but just modify with an extra hole, we can start from this image:

[image]

And proceed to extract the original alpha channel, modify it and push it back into the original:

```
magick image.png \( +clone -alpha extract -fill black -draw "rectangle 10,40 80,80" \) -alpha off -compose copyalpha -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Although the OP seems to be satisfied with this answer, this just covers an area with a white rectangle. With "remove area" I would have expected a "see-through hole" (transparency) in the image, e.g. seeing a checkerboard behind it. Is there maybe a simple way to do this with ImageMagick which I haven't found yet? Like fmw42's solution but without OpenCV?

Comment: @theozh Sure, there are lots of possibilities. If you wanted the white area transparent in my answer, you can just add `-transparent white` before the output filename. You can draw other shapes than rectangles, e.g. circles or polygons or use masks... anything you like. If you want something specific, just ask a new question and add a link to it here so I get notified if I don't happen to see it - which is fairly unlikely. Just say - no problems.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Wouldn't `-transparent white` set all existing white pixels to transparent? I am thinking about an arbitrary colored image. In the meantime, I also found other answers of you to the same/similar topic. I am just surprised that ImageMagick can't simply set, e.g. within a rectangle region like `-region 10x20+110+40` the alpha channel of all pixels to `0xff`.

Comment: @theozh You can draw a transparent rectangle in the existing alpha channel of an image very similarly to how you suggest `magick YOURIMAGE.PNG \( +clone -alpha extract -fill black -draw "rectangle 10,40 80,80" \) -alpha off -compose copyalpha -composite result.png`

Comment: thanks again. I see, duplicating, drawing black rectangle on alpha channel, merge again. Although somehow straightforward, but not obvious for a ImageMagick-beginner. I was searching for a simple boolean operation on the alpha channel within a region. Could you maybe add your above solution to your answer, then I can upvote. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, here is a similar question, but the simple solution there doesn't work for me (version 7.1) https://stackoverflow.com/q/23082308/7295599

Comment: @theozh I have added some extra material to my answer which hopefully will cover your use case better.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a transparent region. Here is how to do that in Imagemagick and Python/OpenCV.

Convert the image to include and opaque alpha channel. Then create a mask that is a white background with a black rectangle. White for where the result should be opaque and black where it should be transparent. Then put the mask into the alpha channel of the image.

Input:

[image]

**Imagemagick**

```
convert barbara3.jpg \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 -fill black -draw "rectangle 50,50 250,150" \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

**Python/OpenCV**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('barbara3.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to image with opaque alpha channel
imgA = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

# create mask of filled black rectangle on white background
# white for opaque and black for transparent
mask = np.full((hh,ww), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.rectangle(mask, (50,50), (250,150), 0, -1)

# put mask into alpha channel of image
result = imgA.copy()
result[:,:,3] = mask

cv2.imwrite('barbara3_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('barbara3_transparent_box.png', result)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Mask:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Download the resulting image to see that it is transparent and not white.